# Where to program with Nim (linux)?

Tags: ide, debian, nim-lang

Just finished full installation of Nim language to my Debian GNU/linux and feel a bit confused, not finding any development kits or at least console commands to try some scripting... Isn't it supposed to be included into instalation packages?

So I'll be thankfull to any advice how to choose between all aviable IDE or interfaces for coding with Nim on Linux.

Comment: Take a look at this article to explore further: https://matthiashager.com/gui-options-for-nim

Comment: This is going to be closed quickly. You can choose between vim, emacs, visual studio... I'm happily using neovim + nim.nvim + syntastic + asyncomplete pluggins.

Comment: PyCharm has an optional free Nim plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nim's main entry point is the `nim` command. As long as you have that, you can compile and run nim programs all right:

```
$ cat > test.nim
echo "Hello nim!"
$ nim c -r test.nim
CC: stdlib_io.nim
CC: stdlib_system.nim
CC: test.nim
Hint:  [Link]
Hint: 14205 LOC; 1.218 sec; 20.496MiB peakmem; Debug build; proj: /private/tmp/t/test.nim; out: /private/tmp/t/test [SuccessX]
Hint: /private/tmp/t/test  [Exec]
Hello nim!
$
```

You can also embed that as a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) into an executable `hi.nim` file and run it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env nim c --hints:off -r

echo "Hi nim scripting!"
```

But you will get a compiled binary without the `.nim` extension along the original file, so it's kind of awkward for scripting.

UPDATE: As suggested by @shirleyquirk you can also save `.nims` files with a special shebang that will run them as [NimScript](https://nim-lang.org/docs/nims.html), which has some limitations compared to normal Nim code but should be fine for most if not all typical scripts.

Comment: if you change the script file to ``hi.nims`` you don't need the ``c -r`` and it wont create a binary either.  
I had to pass ``-S`` to ``env``
``#!/usr/bin/env -S nim --hints:off``
``echo "Hi nim scripting"``

Comment: @shirleyquirk my nim compiler (1.2.6) does not have that option, and it's not documented at https://nim-lang.org/docs/nimc.html either. Is `-S` an experimental feature in the development branch? I do find it at https://nim-lang.org/docs/nims.html though…

Comment: -S is a parameter sent to ``env`` to "pass multiple arguments on shebang lines" https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/env.1.html

Answer (score 4):

Nim isn't included in any development kits as far as I'm concerned. There are a lot of editors with Nim addons though. That includes most popular editors like VSCode, emacs or vim.

If you wanted to you could just use a terminal as an interface with a simple editor.